# Django Filtering based on field values in

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework

I am using Django and I want to use filters in that

My product and company Models are

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    companyId = models.ForeignKey(Comapany)

class Company(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to retrieve Products based on currently user's companyId. So I have implemented My view like this..

```
class ListProducts(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            userCompanyId = request.user.get_profile().companyId
        products = Product.objects.filter(companyId__id__exact = userCompanyId)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My Product Data

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5284ceaae9cfff79368e1f29"),
   "companyId": "528458c4bbe7823947b6d2a3",
   "name": "Apple Juice" 
}
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5267bb4ebbe78220588b4567"),
   "companyId": "52674f02bbe782d5528b4567",
   "name": "Small Soft & Moist Cranberry" 
}
```

My company Data

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("528458c4bbe7823947b6d2a3"),
   "domain": "Manufacturing" 
}
{
   "_id": ObjectId("52674f02bbe782d5528b4567"),
   "domain": "Manufacturing" 
}
```

I am getting output as `[]`

The problem is that while studying filters from django doc I am not able to get it.. SO please help me..

Comment: Paste your User Profile model definition?

Comment: class UserProfile(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User,unique=True)
 
 companyId = models.IntegerField()

Comment: I have updated my question with company model and new view. I am not getting the previous error but getting [] as output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the error. Actually The way of specifying how Product model's `companyId` references `Id` field of company model was wrong. So I saw How `userprofile` references `user` model .I am mentioning here my changes.

Product Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,null=True)
```

View

```
class ListProducts(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    model = Product

    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            userCompanyId = request.user.get_profile().companyId
        products = Product.objects.filter(company = userCompanyId)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

put company_id in Company data like this

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5284ceaae9cfff79368e1f29"),
   "company_id": "528458c4bbe7823947b6d2a3",
   "name": "Apple Juice" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your user profile model's `companyId` is not an integer field, so you should adjust your `Product` model to have a compatible `companyId` type. Oh and yes: don't you have a `Company` model ?

Comment: Oh yes I have Company model. But when I use ForeignKey like companyId = models.ForeignKey(Company) It giving me error as field id cant be null.

Comment: I have updated my question with company model and new view. I am not getting the previous error but getting [] as output

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
ProductSerializer(products)
```

Should be:

```
ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
```

Otherwise though your issue doesn't seem to be related to Django REST framework, just to the particular filter you're running not returning any results.

Double check that `request.user.get_profile()` is returning a correct profile, double check that `userCompanyId` is set correctly, and double check the number of results returned by `Product.objects.filter(companyId__id__exact=userCompanyId).count()`.

I'd guess you either have `userCompanyId` set incorrectly, or there simply *aren't* any matching `Product` records.

Comment: I double checked all things.. userCompanyId is returning "528458c4bbe7823947b6d2a3" But when i return Product.objects.filter(companyId__id__exact=userCompanyId).count() It is giving me 0 as output. Though I am updating my question with all product and company data so u can check where I am wrong. I assume problem is companyId__id__exact

Comment: `"_id": ObjectId("52674f02bbe782d5528b4567"),` <--- These look like MongoDB documents, not Django model instances.  Is that correct?

Comment: It looks like you really want to be doing `Product.objects.filter(companyId__exact = userCompanyId)`, as your companyId field appears to be a string, rather than a relationship.  This is really just a question about correctly filtering mongoengine, (nothing to do with REST framework) so if you don't make progress I'd suggest you rephrase the question *just* focusing on the bit of the query that isn't returning the result you expect, either here or on the mongoengine user group/IRC if there is one.

Comment: I resolved the errors.. Thank you so much for suggestions. I have given answer to demonstrate how i solved that..